# Showing $\cos \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) > 1 - \frac{1}{2n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, induction

I'm interested in showing the inequality
$$ \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) > 1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$$
For all $n$ positive integer. I've tried to proceed by induction and it's easily seen (assuming properties of trigonometric functions) that it holds for $n=1$ but I get stuck on showing it for $n+1$. Once $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ we have $$\cos\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) > \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) > 1- \frac{1}{2 \, n^2}.$$ But I don't know how to get it from here.

Comment: I don't think the induction is the way here. I think one usually shows that $sin (x) $ is less than $x$ and then you could try using this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put
$$f(x)=\cos(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}-1$$

$$f(0)=0$$
for $x\in(0,1]$, $f$ is continuous at $[0,x]$ and differentiable at $(0,x)$ thus by MVT

$$f(x)=xf'(c_1)=x(c_1-\sin(c_1))$$
with $$0<c_1<x\le 1$$
but

$$\sin(c_1)=\sin(c_1)-\sin(0)=c_1\cos(c_2)$$

with  $0<c_2<c_1<x\le 1$ and $\cos(c_2)<1$.
thus $$\sin(c_1)<c_1$$
and finally
$$f(x)>0$$

now replace $x$ by $\frac 1n$.

Comment: $+1$ for using a simple explanation

Answer (score 6):

$$\cos x\le1$$ and equality holds at $x=0$. Integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$$\sin x\le x$$

and equality holds at $x=0$. Integrating from $0$ to $x$,

$$-\cos x\le \frac{x^2}2-1.$$

Take $x=\dfrac1n$.

[image]

You can continue forever and retrieve the Taylor series.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Just a detail: I think your solution can't give the strict inequality, am I right?

Comment: @AnalyticHarmony: The inequalities are strict. When you have $f$ continuous on $[a, b] $ and $f(x) \geq 0,\forall x\in[a, b] $ then $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx\geq 0$. There is equality only when $f(x) =0$ for all $x\in[a, b] $.

Answer (score 3):

Let consider $f(x)=\cos x-1+x^2$ which is even then we can consider $x\ge 0$ and we have

$$f(x)=\cos x-1+x^2\ge 0 \quad f(x)=0 \iff x=0$$

indeed

$$g(x)=f'(x)=x-\sin x\ge 0$$

indeed

$$g'(x)=f''(x)=1-\cos x\ge 0 \quad g'(x)=0 \iff x=k\frac{\pi}2$$

therefore for $x\neq 0$

$$\cos x-1+x^2>0 \implies \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) > 1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$$

Comment: very nice explanation !! :)

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Thanks for the appreciation, it is just a basic application of calculus methods! Bye

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Opsss...I fix the typo! Thanks

Comment: using order derivatives to show the inequality @Salahamam_Fatima

Comment: @AhmadBazzi There was just a typo for $1/x^2$ instead of $x^2$, all the derivation was made according to the second correct option maybe for that you haven't noticed! now it is fixed

Comment: I wanted to point it out but @Salahamam_Fatima was faster than me !!

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I was thinking to the final substitution $x=1/n$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Although there is already an accepted answer I'd like to add a geometric proof of the inequality:

[image]

$$x^2 > s^2 = (1-\cos^2 x) + (1-\cos x)^2 = 2(1- \cos x) \Rightarrow \boxed{\cos x > 1- \frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Nice one! +1 \\